# Block external http requests to a certain folder via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to block all external http requests directed to a certain folder and allow all internal (from the server itself) http requests.

This is my .htaccess file

```
# Denied access folders
RewriteRule ^resources* - [F]
RewriteRule ^assets* - [F]
```

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, it's easier to put an appropriate `.htaccess` file inside each of the folders and avoid `mod_rewrite`:

```
#
# Restrict access by IP address
#
Order Allow,Deny 
Allow from 127.           # localhost
```

You can add as many `Allow` rules as you need.

Comment: I have deleted mod_rewrite rules and created a new .htaccess inside resources folder but i still receive error 403: Forbidden. The apache server is running on my computer and my site is located there too.

Comment: You can inspect your Apache logs to verify the IP address you are connecting from.

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure that this directory can only be accessed by other programs on this domain

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer my-domain.com internal
```

order Deny,allow
Deny from all
allow from env=internal